# bad_record_mac issue on TLS1.2

Tags: openssl

We met an issue about openldap + openssl.

when a multithread client(30 threads) did connect to OPENLDAP server, the server side has "Bad Record MAC" error at TLS handshake randomly.

```
env
openldap+openssl TLS
RHEL7.5 openssl 1.0.2k
openldap2.4.43

TLS configure
The TLS configures are: TLS1.2 ,  ssf=128 and Cipher_Suite="AES:!NULL:!EXPORT" 

Error connection
Error connection progress are
client->server: Client Hello
server->client:Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done
client->server: Client key Exchange
client->server: change cipher spec
client->server: Encryted Handshake Message
Server->client: Alert(Level: Fatal, Decription: Bad Record MAC)env
openldap+openssl TLS
RHEL7.5 openssl 1.0.2k
openldap2.4.43
```

when
when a multithread client(30 threads) connects OPENLDAP server, server side has "Bad Record MAC" error at TLS handshake
.
    how frequence
    This issue occurs randomly, for part connections.

```
TLS configure
The TLS configures are: TLS1.2 ,  ssf=128 and    Cipher_Suite="AES:!NULL:!EXPORT" 

Error connection
Error connection progress are
client->server: Client Hello
server->client:Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done
client->server: Client key Exchange
client->server: change cipher spec
client->server: Encryted Handshake Message
Server->client: Alert(Level: Fatal, Decription: Bad Record MAC)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Bad Record MAC" basically means that the incoming data is bad for some reason. e.g. packet corruption.

Since your mentioned "multithread", the number one cause I've seen for Bad Record MAC" is the misuse of the OpenSSL library in a multithreaded context.  OpenSSL does not support a SSL handle being used in at the same time from multi-threads.  "Bad Record MAC" is normally the result of the packet data being corrupted due to being updated from different threads in the use of a OpenSSL SSL handle.  i.e. a OpenSSL handle is NOT thread-safe.

Multi OpenSSL handles are thread-safe between it's uses of each other, but a single handle is NOT thread-safe.

See this blob [article](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/02/21/threads/) on the subject.

So a common mistake is to allow have two threads for a single SSL handle, one for reading and one for writing (i.e. like what is allowed for socket handles) and thinking it's ok.  With SSL it is NOT.  You really need a single thread (or running context e.g. boost asio strand) that all SSL handle usage is used so that no two SSL handle API calls can't happen at the same time.

Comment: Hi Powell, thanks for your replay. This is a great guide for me. And I checked source code here https://github.com/openldap/openldap/blob/b06f5b0493937fc28f2cc86df1d7f464aa4504d8/libraries/libldap/tls_o.c#L102. The openldap should handle the callback.  But I did debug. This method was not invoked. I think it could be a configuration issue or other. I will check more. Many thanks your help.