# Telegram bot api bad record mac

Tags: go, openssl, ssl-certificate, telegram-bot

Nearly three month ago my bot was broke with error like this

```
2021/07/23 17:34:39 Authorized on account SomeBot

2021/07/23 17:34:39 {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

2021/07/23 17:35:28 http: TLS handshake error from 91.108.6.64:33364: local error: tls: bad record MAC

2021/07/23 17:35:28 http: TLS handshake error from 91.108.6.64:33436: local error: tls: bad record MAC

2021/07/23 17:35:30 http: TLS handshake error from 91.108.6.64:33792: local error: tls: bad record MAC

2021/07/23 17:35:30 http: TLS handshake error from 91.108.6.64:33828: local error: tls: bad record MAC
```

I think it old certificate error and generate new from tg documentation example
https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout bot.key -x509 -days 365 -out bot.pem -subj "/C=RU/ST=Test/L=Test/O=Example Inc/CN=domain.EXAMPLE"
```

webhook set

```
_, err = bot.SetWebhook(tgbotapi.NewWebhookWithCert(fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/%s", hook, token), "bot.pem"))
```

and server

```
go http.ListenAndServeTLS("0.0.0.0:8443", "bot.pem", "bot.key", nil)
```

but error not fixed, logs are same, how to fix this?

Comment: about `bad record MAC` https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381232/4466350 / https://security.stackexchange.com/a/39846 / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154617/how-to-troubleshoot-ssl-bad-record-mac-exception

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Mine was working for a while, and then this just started happening ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

I met such situation, when changed domain name for webhook.
I regenerated .crt, .csr and .key for new domain (CN changed for new domain) and it works again.